# how to conditional render a styled component in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `styled-component` that I want to render only when the screen size is above 480. I tried doing that by getting a reference to the element and disabling it. but that didn't work. I set the `display` property to `none`but then the button is still there it's clickable.

Here is my code

```
 console.log(window.screen.width);
  if(window.screen.width <= 480) {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("Button1")
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="control">
        <Circle onClick={handleVideoToggle}>
          <img src={video ? Video : VideoOff} />
          </Circle>
        <Circle onClick={handleAudioToggle}>
          <img src={audio ? Mic : MicOff} />
        </Circle>
        <Circle onClick={handleScreenToggle}>
          <img className = "Button1" src={screen ? Screen : ScreenOff} />
        </Circle>
        <Circle onClick={handleCallDisconnect}>
          <img src={End} />
        </Circle>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Controls;

const 
  Circle = styled.div`
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    :not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  `,
  Image = styled.img`
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  `;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove that "if" block at the top.  You can conditionally include Circle/Button in what you return, like this:

```
  const isSmall = window.screen.width <= 480;
  return (
    <>
      <div className="control">
        <Circle onClick={handleVideoToggle}>
          <img src={video ? Video : VideoOff} />
          </Circle>
        <Circle onClick={handleAudioToggle}>
          <img src={audio ? Mic : MicOff} />
        </Circle>
        {!isSmall && (<Circle onClick={handleScreenToggle}>
              <img className = "Button1" src={screen ? Screen : ScreenOff} />
            </Circle>)
        }
        <Circle onClick={handleCallDisconnect}>
          <img src={End} />
        </Circle>
      </div>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete if statement and make it work with css media queries :

```
const Circle = styled.div`
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    display: none;
  }
  :not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  `,
```

It is still clickable because you set OnClick handler for your Curcle component not for img

Comment: I tried that already. but then the button stays at its position and is clickable. it's just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can just conditionally render the StyledComponent in react as below. But for referring an element you can use react `ref` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("Button1")`.

```js
console.log(window.screen.width);

  const isAbove480  = window.screen.width > 480;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="control">
        
        <Circle onClick={handleVideoToggle}>
          <img src={video ? Video : VideoOff} />
          </Circle>
        <Circle onClick={handleAudioToggle}>
          <img src={audio ? Mic : MicOff} />
        </Circle>

        { isAbove480 ? (<Circle onClick={handleScreenToggle}>
          <img className = "Button1" src={screen ? Screen : ScreenOff} />
        </Circle>) : null }

        
        <Circle onClick={handleCallDisconnect}>
          <img src={End} />
        </Circle>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Controls;

const 
  Circle = styled.div`
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    :not(:first-child) {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
  `,
  Image = styled.img`
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  `;
```